# Firebase Security Rules for users to read and write their own data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working with Flutter and Firebase and came up with the following Firebase structure.

[image: Room collections]

Room and user collections:

[image: 2]

I want users to be able to read and write their data.
And I wrote the following rules:

[image: rules]

For getting rooms, I've following code in Flutter:

```
     Stream<List<RoomModel>> getRooms() {
        var user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
        return _db
            .collection('rooms')
            // .where("userId", "==", user.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
                .map((document) => RoomModel.fromFirestore(document.data()))
                .toList());
      }
```

Room Model:

```
    // import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    
    class RoomModel {
      final String roomId;
      final double price;
      final String location;
      final String userId;
    
      RoomModel(this.roomId, this.price, this.location, this.userId);
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        // final firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        // var user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
        return {
          'roomId': roomId,
          'price': price,
          'userId': userId,
          'location': location,
        };
      }
    
      RoomModel.fromFirestore(Map firestore)
          : roomId = firestore['roomId'],
            price = firestore['price'],
            location = firestore['location'],
            userId = firestore['userId'];
    }
```

But still, I'm getting all the rooms, including other user's room.

And later I also wanted to read all the rooms. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I would add subcollections. `users/USERID/rooms/`. To get All rooms use `collectionGroup` by adding an index

```
 var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
 var myReviews = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('room')
   .where('userId', '==', myUserId);
 myReviews.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    // Do something with these rooms!
 })
```

Read More here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

Comment: .where('userId', '==', myUserId);

How do i use this in .dart file itself? This pops error.
 The above code that i wrote was in dart.

Comment: Check this flutter fire example https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying

Comment: One more thing, you are thinking like its SQL db, thats why you got confused. Think as userCollection has RoomSubCollection also roomCollection has userSubcollection, so when you call user/userID/rooms/ it will give you a collection of documents that are in rooms also in room collection roomID you get which users are there. Sometime you need to do a Batch write to add a room in user collection and a user in room collection same time. Forget foreign keys, there is no join in firestore

Comment: I agree with the above comments. You data model needs to be restructured to add subcollections. This will help with your security rules and accessing the data.